# SQL query to find the shortest route between 2 points

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that has three fields: `Origin`, `Destination` and `Distance`.

How can I write a query to find the shortest route from origin to destination?

```
 Origin     Destination        Distance 
-----------------------------------------
   A             B                 10
   B             C                 20
   C             E                 30
   B             F                 5
   F             E                 6
```

For example we want the shortest route from C to F the answer will be :

```
     C---->F
C---->B then B---->F
```

Comment: It's not possible to implement something like Djkstra's algorithm in a query: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm

Comment: Agree with @tvanfosson. You are best implementing this in something like C# and use SQL-CLR if you want to do it in SQL.

Comment: Is this a teoretical question or live example? If live example, then you can probably set some limit for the maximum hops and then join the same table couple of times. You can also think about recursive stored procedures but if you need it then you've probably should move the logic to the code of the application and not execute it in database.

Answer (score 0):

In line with the comments already made, I'd suggest you take a look at this: 
[Graph Algorithms with MapReduce](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~jimmylin/cloud-2008-Fall/Session5.ppt) and [MapReduce Links](http://www.dbms2.com/2008/08/25/mapreduce-links/)

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve kinda similar problem. Only there was only one hop allowed. It worked, but the solution was very cumbersome. I dread to think what procedures you need to write for your problem. SQL is not really intended for your problem.

You'll be much better off reading data from database and deciding on the best route in some other environment, like LISP or Haskel.

So I do agree with the above answers/comments that there is no trivial answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it can be done using recursive CTE. You can find the below code for reference. Let me know if i miss anything.

```
DECLARE @x CHAR(5)= 'C';
DECLARE @y CHAR(5)= 'F';

WITH cte
     AS (
     SELECT CASE
                WHEN origin = @x
                THEN destination
                ELSE origin
            END destination,
            distance,
            CAST(RTRIM(CASE
                           WHEN origin = @x
                           THEN origin
                           ELSE destination
                       END) AS VARCHAR) AS rt
     FROM troute
     WHERE(origin = @x
           OR destination = @x)
     UNION ALL
     SELECT a.destination,
            a.distance + b.distance distance,
            CAST(RTRIM(b.rt)+'-'+a.origin AS VARCHAR) rt
     FROM troute a
          JOIN cte b ON a.origin = b.destination)
     SELECT id,
            destination,
            distance,
            RTRIM(rt)+'-'+RTRIM(@y)
     FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY distance) ID,
           *
    FROM cte
    WHERE destination = @y
) a
     WHERE a.ID = 1;
```